# Directory path in Resource vs String

Tags: windows, spring-boot, directory, spring-annotations

How do I give the directory path for Resource in spring boot project on Windows?
I get the proper path/format when I use it as string.

This is what I have in application.properties

```
input.file = C:\\Users\\termine\\dev\\sample2.csv
```

I used this class just to test the directory path it throws:

```
@Component
public class pathtesting {

    public static String prop;

    @Value("${input.file}")
    public void setProp(String prop) {
        this.prop= prop;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("================== " + prop + "================== ");
    }
}
```

It throws the proper path I have in windows 10. Output of pathtesting:

```
================== C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv==================
```

But when I use it as Resource as follows:

```
    @Value("${input.file}")
    private Resource inputResource;

    .
    .
     @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<PE> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<PE> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PE>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(inputResource);
        return itemReader;
    }
```

..it throws this error:

```
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): ServletContext resource [/C:/Users/termine/dev/sample2.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:146)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

I tried several possible ways with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference your resource as a file like this:

```
@Value("file:${input.file}")
private Resource inputResource;
```

Comment: I updated to MultiResourceItemReader and now we are using Resource[].

This worked fine:

`
@Value("file:///C:/Users/termine/dev/source/*.csv")
private Resource[] inputResources;
`

But when I added like this in application properties as follows:

`
src.folder = C:\\Users\\termine\\dev\\source\\*.csv
`

I get this error
`
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve resource location pattern [C:\Users\termine\dev\source\*.csv]: ServletContext resource [/C:] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
`

Comment: Check that you are using  the `file` prefix this way `@value("file:${src.folder}")`